# Map requests based on subdomain

Tags: nginx

How do I map the subdomain that I don't have to rewrite the URI?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  cooking.com user.cooking.com admin.cooking.com;
    root   html/cooking/public;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  FEED_ENV  default;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }
}
```

So basically WHen a user access `admin.cooking.com` it should request for `/index.php/admin/`. I was thinking of using `if` but [if is bad](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

Comment: How many of these hosts do you have?

Comment: what do you mean @MichaelHampton

Comment: Are you just trying to set up two subdomains, or more, or all of them?

Comment: only the two subdomains @MichaelHampton

Comment: How URL does passed to PHP? You should use `fastcgi_param URL_VAR ...;` and several `server` blocks.

Comment: The `if` statement is perfectly safe as long as you only use directives from the [rewrite](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) module inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need separate server blocks for this.

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/php.conf

location @php {
  fastcgi_param FEED_ENV default;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

... and your server config:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/server.conf;

listen 80;
root html/cooking/public;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
include fastcgi_params;

location / {
  location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
}
```

... and your final virtual host config:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/virtual_hosts.conf

server {
  server_name cooking.com;
  include sites-available/server.conf;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include sites-available/php.conf;
}

server {
  server_name user.cooking.com;
  include sites-available/server.conf;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php/user/$args;
  include sites-available/php.conf;
}

server {
  server_name admin.cooking.com;
  include sites-available/server.conf;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php/admin/$args;
  include sites-available/php.conf;
}
```

You only create a symbolic link in `sites-enabled` to the `virtual_hosts.conf`!

Because I don't know your exact environment (the backend and how it handles the incoming URLs) I can't give you a perfect config. But this should be a good starting point.

Comment: that can't be because it must make the request on the index.php file, `admin` and `user` are not a directory.

Comment: I edited my answer.